# Why does spsolve() function output a vector?

Tags: python, vector, scipy

F is a CSR sparse matrix.

```
  (0, 0)    28.9009663001
  (0, 1)    -9.21359549996
  ...
  (7, 6)    -10.2135955
  (7, 7)    30.9009663001
```

C is also a CSR sparse matrix.

```
(0, 0)  1.0782887739
(1, 0)  -1.33369825452
(2, 0)  1.74824228278
(3, 0)  -2.55552434318
(4, 0)  3.08435514293
(5, 0)  -1.94369861339
(6, 0)  1.47753839244
(7, 0)  -2.09583584401
```

P = spsolve(F,C) outputs the followings:

```
[ 0.02897775 -0.02418963  0.03217452 -0.0457709   0.06740877 -0.03168885
0.01767905 -0.06140939]
```

why is the output a vector even when both F and C are sparse matrices?
The Scipy Reference Guide says that "If C is a vector, then the output is a vector."
But now C is a sparse. but the output is still in form of vectors.

I think I can just sparse.csr_matrix(P). but is it going to lower the speed?

Answer (score 0):

This is because spsolve converts sparse column matrices (like your `C`) to dense vectors: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.13.0/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py#L92

It looks like your output is dense, anyway, so converting it to a sparse representation will only make things slower.

Comment: But in the scipy Reference Guide, it says the output can be either in form of sparse and dense vectors? What can I do to make it output a sparse matrix so that I dont need to make my program runs slow? speed is very crucial in my program..Thanks

Comment: The output will only be sparse when both `C` and `F` are sparse, and they both have >1 columns. I suspect that trying to force sparse matrices will actually make your code slower, so I'd advise profiling your code now and finding the bottlenecks.